How to use Named Credential when apiKey is part of endpoint?
We are using the HERE api to retrieve geolocations. We had the API Key hardcoded, and yes, of course this is wrong. We want instead use a Named Credential.
Using below endpoint works:
String address = ...;
String apiKey = 'VALUE_API_Key';
...
req.setEndpoint(https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q= + address + '&apiKey=' + apiKey);
...

I rewrote this to the following:
String namedCredential = 'nmspc__hereapi';
String url = 'https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=';
String address = ...;
...
req.setEndpoint('callout:' + namedCredential + '/v1/geocode?q=' + address + '&apiKey={!$Credential.HEREAPI.HEREAPIKey}');
...

I stored the api key in the principle of the external credential called HEREAPI and the parameter itself is called HEREAPIKey. I set Allow Formulas in HTTP Header to true.
I receive error:
Illegal character in opaque part at index X: callout:msf__hereapi/v1/geocode?q=Address&apiKey={!$Credential.HEREAPI.HEREAPIKey}
I am clearly doing something wrong to set the endpoint. But I can't seem to find the right examples.
Any help on how to set the correct endpoint would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

@identigral, you are correct. I looked into it. This seems it is only possible to use merge fields in setHeader.
Thanks for the redirection.
